# Reload Ajax div from Anchor within is failing

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html, wordpress

I have a div (i) wich has content load within it with an Ajax `.load()`.

Once that div (i) is loaded, there are two anchor links which open a previous or next post.

These next and previous links work fine to reload the entire page to their respective generated urls, but I need them to load within the Ajax post they were loaded into in the first place.

What's happening when they're clicked, is the current post that is already loaded in the Ajax div just reloads. The next or previous post `href` is ignored.

Anchor structure for next/previous post:

```
        <div class="previousNav">
                <?php $prev_post = get_previous_post();
             if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>
              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                &larr;</a>
             <?php endif; ?>
         </div>

         <div class="nextNav">
            <?php $next_post = get_next_post();
             if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>
              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                &rarr;</a>
             <?php endif; ?>
         </div>
```

jScript functions for the above html:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.previousNav a').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var post_id = $(this).attr("rel"); 
            $(".aboveTheFold").load("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajax-post/",{id: post_id}); console.log();
            return false;
        });
        $('.nextNav a').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var post_id = $('.nextNav a').attr("rel");
            $(".aboveTheFold").load("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajax-post/",{id: post_id});
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Not getting any output from the `console.log()` or any errors in Chrome console.

Is this an Ajax error?

Comment: The "duplicate" question does not exist anymore, I'm voting to reopen it since you cannot choose another duplicate question

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation with `.on()` method:

```
$('body').on('click', '.previousNav a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var post_id = $(this).attr("rel"); 
    $(".aboveTheFold").load("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajax-post/",{id: post_id}); 
    return false;
});

$('body').on('click', '.nextNav a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var post_id = $('.nextNav a').attr("rel");
    $(".aboveTheFold").load("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajax-post/",{id: post_id});
    return false;
});
```

Because your `.previousNav a` and `.nextNav a` will refresh after each ajax load, the event handler will not 
fired for the second time. But with event delegation, you attach the event handler to
current and future elements.

---

References:

- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - jQuery API Documentation

Comment: I really like the way you're going with this. Makes a lot of sense to work this way. Using this method I've put the script into the header and footer (not at the same time) to see it's effectiveness, but unfortunately this isn't working with the setup I have for some reason. Might have to figure out a different avenue for showing next posts.. might have to cave and make a sliding jquery post slider or a disgusting iframe.

Comment: Also, if your'e interested in seeing the markup, please check the live code at theciv dot com (trying not to spam SO)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 1.8 and above

```
 $('.previousNav').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var post_id = $(this).attr("rel"); 
            $(".aboveTheFold").load("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajax-post/",{id: post_id}); console.log();
            return false;
        });
```

This uses delegation to just watch for '.previousNav' and register the provided function for all `a`, no matter when they were added (The same goes for the `nextNav`)

Comment: Unfortunately it operates as if the `event.preventDefault();` wasn't there. Instead of loading the content into the specified div, it refreshes the entire page.